# Glitch / Blink video on OSX (Macbook pro 15' mid-2012 no retina) and firefox 40+

Tags: macbook-pro, video, firefox

I currently have a problem with my macbook 15' mid-2012 (No retina) with Yosemite. When I watch videos (e.g. Youtube) via Firefox, sometime for a microsecond the video becomes blue then comes back to the original color. This problem happens randomly; therefore I have no idea if it's come from Firefox, Youtube or my macbook. I tried with safari and this problem didn't happen, but I can be sure.

Moreover, other problems have appeared at exactly same time. It might have a link. My macbook has accidentally rebooted and hasn't produced a log. Finder has accidentally stopped and hasn't been not able to restart.

I have did a complete reinstallation of OS X but the problem is still there. I have also execute an Apple Hardware Test, but all seems ok. Yet I have suspicion of a bad RAM or GPU. All my softwares are up to date.

Finder error report :

```
Process:               Finder [1081]
Path:                  /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/Contents/MacOS/Finder
Identifier:            Finder
Version:               ???
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Finder [1081]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2015-10-04 13:57:14.046 +0200
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.5 (14F27)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        55A7EE98-4ECA-E59F-CC25-4FADA49D6699

Sleep/Wake UUID:       EF4D15D8-E4F2-41A7-9680-E50081FD2B9D

Time Awake Since Boot: 42000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       2400 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0

Exception Type:        EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries

Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Suggestions.framework/Versions/A/Suggestions
  Referenced from: /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/Contents/MacOS/Finder
  Reason: malformed mach-o image: load command #22 length (0) too small in /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Suggestions.framework/Versions/A/Suggestions

Binary Images:
    0x7fff6db81000 -     0x7fff6dbb7887  dyld (353.2.3) <B1B370A5-479F-3533-8AD7-97B687D4F989> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff8d119000 -     0x7fff8d228ff3  com.apple.desktopservices (1.9.3 - 1.9.3) <FEE11342-5BC4-37A7-8169-DA48BE17B9C9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DesktopServicesPriv.framework/Versions/A/DesktopServicesPriv
    0x7fff8d39f000 -     0x7fff8d417ff7  com.apple.SystemConfiguration (1.14.4 - 1.14) <3DFFD7F7-BD23-3F4C-A209-C4A0D99F6573> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/Versions/A/SystemConfiguration
    0x7fff8e708000 -     0x7fff8e7aafff  com.apple.Bluetooth (4.3.6 - 4.3.6f3) <E5DC1699-2727-329C-A843-C80CE9A6CD7B> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOBluetooth.framework/Versions/A/IOBluetooth
    0x7fff8eefe000 -     0x7fff8ef05fff  com.apple.NetFS (6.0 - 4.0) <C263C8F8-F284-3101-AC82-A97A81716063> /System/Library/Frameworks/NetFS.framework/Versions/A/NetFS
    0x7fff8ef06000 -     0x7fff8f170ff7  com.apple.imageKit (2.6.1 - 850) <612201FE-768E-386B-82E3-764038B40120> /System/Library/Frameworks/Quartz.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageKit.framework/Versions/A/ImageKit
    0x7fff8f283000 -     0x7fff8f343ff7  com.apple.backup.framework (1.6.5 - 1.6.5) <86396038-33EA-3046-9F70-093A3D6407D4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Backup.framework/Versions/A/Backup
    0x7fff8fa83000 -     0x7fff8fae0fff  com.apple.QuickLookFramework (5.0 - 675.43) <506D60B4-B188-3D0A-9187-0404A60A9B06> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/Versions/A/QuickLook
    0x7fff90736000 -     0x7fff90756fff  com.apple.IconServices (47.1 - 47.1) <E83DFE3B-6541-3736-96BB-26DC5D0100F1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IconServices.framework/Versions/A/IconServices
    0x7fff9075b000 -     0x7fff90798ff3  com.apple.bom (14.0 - 193.6) <3CE5593D-DB28-3BFD-943E-6261006FA292> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Versions/A/Bom
    0x7fff913f9000 -     0x7fff915a9ff3  com.apple.QuartzCore (1.10 - 361.19) <F815B60E-75E3-3263-BE93-27A49882CF58> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Versions/A/QuartzCore
    0x7fff929f9000 -     0x7fff92a07ff7  com.apple.opengl (11.1.2 - 11.1.2) <5F355713-4637-33CD-9CBA-4B4CA43FB0FE> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL
    0x7fff9314d000 -     0x7fff93237ff7  com.apple.QuickLookUIFramework (5.0 - 675.43) <011DEB49-0FB3-3E44-9D99-D89ADD59A3CC> /System/Library/Frameworks/Quartz.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/QuickLookUI.framework/Versions/A/QuickLookUI
    0x7fff9608a000 -     0x7fff9626fff7  libicucore.A.dylib (531.48) <3CD34752-B1F9-31D2-865D-B5B0F0BE3111> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
    0x7fff965f4000 -     0x7fff96620fff  com.apple.framework.SystemAdministration (1.0 - 1.0) <9F77597C-BAB8-3D86-B6CC-96D54D89E6AE> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SystemAdministration.framework/Versions/A/SystemAdministration
    0x7fff96954000 -     0x7fff96983ff7  com.apple.CommerceKit (1.2.0 - 376.29) <FC810A52-983A-3F19-89C0-3EBB464990C4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommerceKit.framework/Versions/A/CommerceKit
    0x7fff979b7000 -     0x7fff97a05ff7  com.apple.ImageCaptureCore (6.3 - 6.3) <75B5043C-9EF0-3CD2-875D-12813F0A73D3> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageCaptureCore.framework/Versions/A/ImageCaptureCore
    0x7fff97a06000 -     0x7fff97a06fff  com.apple.CoreServices (62 - 62) <C69DA8A7-B536-34BF-A93F-1C170E2C6D58> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices
    0x7fff98752000 -     0x7fff987c4fff  com.apple.framework.IOKit (2.0.2 - 1050.20.2) <09C0518C-90DF-3FC3-96D6-34D35F72C8EF> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
    0x7fff9aa67000 -     0x7fff9ab8fff7  com.apple.coreui (2.1 - 308.6) <9E0E9C6A-68F5-34C1-A17C-96226D401D4D> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/Versions/A/CoreUI
    0x7fff9c278000 -     0x7fff9c27dfff  com.apple.DiskArbitration (2.6 - 2.6) <0DFF4D9B-2AC3-3B82-B5C5-30F4EFBD2DB9> /System/Library/Frameworks/DiskArbitration.framework/Versions/A/DiskArbitration
    0x7fff9ccd4000 -     0x7fff9ccd4fff  com.apple.ApplicationServices (48 - 48) <5BF7910B-C328-3BF8-BA4F-CE52B574CE01> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices

Model: MacBookPro9,1, BootROM MBP91.00D3.B0B, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.3 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 2.1f175
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000, Intel HD Graphics 4000, Built-In
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M, NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M, PCIe, 512 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54333235533643465238432D50422020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54333235533643465238432D50422020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xF5), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.15.166.24.3)
Bluetooth: Version 4.3.6f3 16238, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: APPLE HDD TOSHIBA MK5065GSXF, 500,11 GB
Serial ATA Device: MATSHITADVD-R   UJ-8A8
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: IR Receiver
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 25.1
```

Could you help me in this matter ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found what was the problem. Firefox has an option "hardware acceleration" which seems to not be stable. It allows to use GPU instead CPU when it is possible.

Here is the link which helps me to solve my problem :
https://support.mozilla.org/fr/questions/1049291